# WiFi stopped working not Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, drivers

I'm using Debian 8 and WiFi has stopped working.

When I look for the networks by the gnome it appears that there are no available networks, I've tried a lot but it does not work again.

## ifconfig

```
<code>eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.0.160  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
inet6 fe80::3e07:71ff:fe6b:3c28  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 3c:07:71:6b:3c:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 5693  bytes 6018023 (5.7 MiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 4349  bytes 1187030 (1.1 MiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
loop  txqueuelen 1  (Loopback Local)
RX packets 223  bytes 20884 (20.3 KiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 223  bytes 20884 (20.3 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
ether 86:06:87:cd:7c:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 18</code>
```

## iwconfig

```
<code>eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
  Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
  Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
  Encryption key:off
  Power Management:off</code>
```

## ip a

`1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:07:71:6b:3c:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.160/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3e07:71ff:fe6b:3c28/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:3c:5c:fc:b0:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

## lspci

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 
09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT 
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller 
(rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 
04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 
04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 
(rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 
(rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 
(rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 
(rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 
[AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 
01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 
PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)`

I already installed the drivers (it was working) I do not know why it stopped working. I do not want to format the computer

Comment: "_I've tried a lot but it does not work again_" please expand this statement in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the wpa_supplicant.service that was not starting.
After finding the problem was easy, with some commands everything is working.

wpa_supplicant.service was not able to access libssl1.0.2

Solution:

```
apt install --reinstall libssl1.0.2 <br>
service wpa_supplicant restart <br>
reboot
```